# How to Get AccessToken Dynamically from Cognito OAuth2.0 in Electron JS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, electron, amazon-cognito, access-token

Hello i use Electron JS for a desktop app which is related to a cloud plateform from which in needto get a list of Patients.

As far as now i can get it but with a static AccessToken. I really struggled to get it dynamic, please help.

Here is my code :

This is my configuration file where i specify Cognito Parameters :

```
export default {
s3: {
  REGION: 'YOUR_S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_REGION',
  BUCKET: 'YOUR_S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_NAME',
},
apiGateway: {
  REGION: 'YOUR_API_GATEWAY_REGION',
  URL: 'YOUR_API_GATEWAY_URL',
},
cognito: {
  REGION: 'eu-west-1',
  USER_POOL_ID: 'eu-west-1_P0Jcr7nig',
  APP_CLIENT_ID: '4m1utu56hjm835dshts9jg63ou',
  IDENTITY_POOL_ID: 'YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
  authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
  AUTHENTICATION_FLOW_TYPE: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
},
API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: 'PatientsList',
        endpoint: 'https://uo992r7huf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Stage/patients',
        //endpoint: 'https://uo992r7huf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Stage',
      },
    ],
  },
};

Auth.signIn({
 username: process.env.username,
 password: process.env.password,
}).then().catch(err => {
 console.log(err)});
```

In another file this is my getaccesstoken function which i export to the main

```
function getAccessToken() {
 const poolData = { 
  UserPoolId : COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
 ClientId : COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
};
const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var authenticationData = {
      Username : process.env.username, // your username here
      Password : process.env.password, // your password here,
      authenticationFlowType: process.env.AUTHENTICATION_FLOW_TYPE,
      Pool : userPool
  };
  var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(
    authenticationData);
  var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(authenticationData);
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
       console.log(err);
      },
  });
}
```

And finally here is how i get the data in main :

The declarations :

```
  const  { Auth } = require('./cognitoAuth');
 const theAccessToken = require('./cognitoAuth');
```

The code :

```
  //Get Data From Cloud ECS
  const API_URL = 'https://uo992r7huf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Stage/patients';
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //Authorization: theAccessToken.getAccessToken()
    Authorization: "eyJraWQiOiJBbE1DZnBCTHYyVUlNazhXSG4xaTk4RG1QNlFmcFpSSjFaSW1qcVVFZnVBPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.LYvzPRBxvKw2P3gHwV8NhYPg_EB3F7ZK2F5HpRWHtBHksr6D4N5Fw56ZVupkRCxVJSq0f93DdljI7BBcBnp9d_hpLzmJLTfBhA3t870omTxalTqpGXN_SvsZmuwcfCX-awn1Um6x_-fhq3zcfPkB9FBljbtwPN-kvCc-Iynei9anVxXI686nIbkfbYfnuRnHrbY0vg8FtyDIDBMv277FPoJ96NwPD4mJvNBxQHi_KfWxQ1DmLiAC6c_l2jP_wawAPBv788CjD_8OlKBbjAHinGEkaL1K9vjI5MhNPyTA5ym1IaWar7Jr8RkUDzQGvqEUPKoOUe9PswmOOxLBjehMgQ"
    };
    //console.log('Token Value:', theAccessToken.getAccessToken());
    const getPatients = async(API_URL) => {
      try {
        //get data from cloud specifiying get method and headers which contain token
        const response = await fetch(API_URL,{
          method: 'GET', headers: headers}
          );
        var listPatients = await response.json();
        listPatients.items.forEach(patient => {
          //Checking what i got
          console.log(patient);
        });
        } catch(err) {
          console.log("Error" + err);
        }
        };
       getPatients(API_URL);
```

Now when i make it dynamic by specifying theAccessToken.getAccessToken
**I get this error, USER_SRP is not enabled even if specify it, when i asked team told me the cloud service doesn't want to enable it.
So how can i get this access token please?**

Answer (score 2):

For a desktop app it is recommended to do these 2 things, according to [security guidance](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252):

- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- Login via the system browser, so that the app never sees the user's password

I have a couple of Electron code samples that use Cognito, which you can easily run - maybe start here:

- [First desktop app](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer using PKCE certainly fits what i ask for, but when i asked the cloud team, they said it should work even if they don't activate USER_SRP_AUTH, therefore, with all the thanks i have for you, what i am seeking is to know where in my code is the fault. Because according to them, it should work. Thanks

Comment: I don't like the look of your solution since your application code gains access to the user's password, which is very much against OAuth principles. It feels like the library you have chosen is vendor specific and requires a USER_SRP_AUTH setting. This seems to be a non portable AWS specific feature based on multiple authentication challenges. Do you need this functionality? At first glance I agree with your cloud team that the coded approach may need more thought. I would start by understanding OAuth standards before adopting a coded solution you may have seen in an online vendor web page.